# "Find shortcut" can't find existing shortcut in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine, ideavim

I am trying to give RubyMine another try with ideavim plugin (I am switching from vim). I was trying to map `^L` to "Next Splitter" but it didn't work (instead it seems to be opening all of the previously opened files until it reaches the projet readme).

I used "Find shortcut" to determine if maybe this shortcut is defined somewhere else but the only result was the shortcut that I set (Goto Next Splitter). I also tried to remove it completely and the behaviour is still the same. How can I find out what is the shortcut for `^L` and why it seems like I can't override it?

It is a fresh install on OS X, no settings were imported, my .ideavimrc is empty.

UPDATE: So thanks to @Feedforward comment, I figured out that this was actually ideavim shortcut. What I missed is that when I added `^L` to keymap, it was shown in ideavim conflicting shortcuts (Preferences -> Editor -> Vim Emulation). There were two ways to solve this:

1. In "Vim Emulation" choose "IDE" as "Handler" for the shortcut.
2. Remove the shortcut and add it in the `.ideavimrc` (which seemed a bit more reasonable to me).

```
nmap <C-l> :action NextSplitter<CR>
nmap <C-h> :action PrevSplitter<CR>
```

So now the question that I still have: how can I find out what is this shortcut for "ideavim"?

Comment: Does it work well with IdeaVim disabled?

Comment: @Feedforward actually it does work! Updating the question, thanks.

Comment: Could you please check that `Preferences | Editor | Vim Emulation` has `IDE` handler for `^L`?

Comment: No, it was there only when I had it in `Keymap`